# If a sequence is not bounded above, there exists an subsequnce that convergest to + infinity

Tags: analysis

i have no idea how to solve that
i have tried by saything that there is a subsequence that always increases but nothing seems to work out

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos They already have two answers from before you posted your comment, but I appreciate that you're saying the question should have shown more effort on their part.

Comment: i am greek so my answers are in greek thats why i ididint post them 
and im not yet used to english mathematic terms

Answer (score 5):

Choose $n_1$ such that $a_{n_1} >1$ then $n_2>n_1$ such that $a_{n_2} >2$ and so on.

Comment: and why would that help me, i really cant see the solution...

Comment: @ΛάμπροςΑθανασόπουλος Well, that constructs a subsequence that converges to $+\infty$, as desired (you may want to additionlly enforce $n_2>n_1$ etc)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is that a strict mathemattic solution tho?